# How do I get a reference to a destructured structure or fall through?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have `struct Boo` inside an `enum Foo`. I use a `match` that checks different variants. To jump to one of the variants, I need to destructure `Boo`, but after I jump to it I need a reference to it:

```
enum Foo {
    Boo(Boo),
    //other variants
}

struct Boo {
    field: Option<String>,
    //other fields
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = unimplemented!();

    match foo {
        Foo::Boo(Boo {
            field: Some(ref name),
        }) if name.starts_with("moo") || name.starts_with("boo") => {
            // I need a reference to boo here
            unimplemented!();
        }
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

Note that in the code hidden by `_ => unimplemented!()`, I also check the `Foo::Boo` variant with another `name.starts_with` and without an `if`.

Is this possible? If it is impossible, maybe it's possible to return control to the `match` checking code path after test failure? Is there another workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a **Binding** syntax in pattern matches, unfortunately it's not allowed to bind inside a binding...

A guard + binding can be helpful as it allows matching *other* fields in `Boo`, while having a limited guard:

```
fn has_expected_name(name: &str) -> bool {
    name.starts_with("boo") || name.starts_with("moo")
}

match foo {
    Foo::Boo(ref boo @ Boo { field: Some(_) })
        if has_expected_name(boo.field.as_ref().unwrap()) =>
    {
        unimplemented!("{:?}", boo);
    }
    _ => unimplemented!(),
}
```

This makes it clear, even if the definition of `has_expected_name` is a bit far away, that it only accesses `boo.field`, and nothing else.

---

It's also possible to just use the binding:

```
match foo {
    Foo::Boo(ref boo @ Boo {
        field: Some(_),
    }) if boo.field.unwrap().starts_with("moo") || boo.field.unwrap().starts_with("boo") => {
        unimplemented!("{:?}", boo);
    }
    _ => unimplemented!(),
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My workaround for these cases is to write an auxiliary function to implement the guard. That way you can capture `boo` without destructuring and still use the match guard:

```
fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = unimplemented!();

    fn is_my_boo(boo: &Boo) -> bool {
        match boo.field {
            Some(ref name) => name.starts_with("boo") || name.starts_with("moo"),
            None => false
        }
    }

    match foo {
        Foo::Boo(ref boo) if is_my_boo(boo) => {
            //you can reference boo here
            unimplemented!();
        }
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

You could also write the auxiliary function as a closure if you like, but for pure functions I prefer the `fn` syntax.

If you feel that local functions are ugly, you could try and mash up the whole function body in the guard, with mandatory extra parenthesis:

```
fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = unimplemented!();

    match foo {
        Foo::Boo(ref boo) if {
                match boo.field {
                    Some(ref name) => name.starts_with("boo") || name.starts_with("moo"),
                    None => false
                }
            } => {
            //you can reference boo here
            unimplemented!();
        }
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) on `boo.field` instead of `match`: `boo.field.map_or(false, |name| name.starts_with("boo") || name.starts_with("moo"))`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed. And now it is reduced to one line and can be used easily in the main guard. In the auxiliary function I need to add `as_ref()` (`boo.field.as_ref().map_or(...)`), as I would expect it, but curiously in the match guard it works without it. Maybe because of the `match` ergonomics?

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why the `as_ref` is needed only in the function :/

Comment: @MatthieuM. And the same in your answer, I would expect the `unwrap()` to try and consume the `field` and fail because it is borrowed, but it just works...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think I got why you don't need `as_ref()` in the `match` even though `boo` is borrowed: it is because of the `let foo: Foo = unimplemented!();`, the compiler sees that the `match` will never be executed and the borrow checked goes into `everything goes` mode. Replacing that line with `let foo: Foo = Foo::Boo(Boo { field: Some("x".to_string()) });` fails as expected.